# VB Winforms use for loop to reference control of specific number

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Ok so say i have 9 buttons named btn1 to btn9 i need to reference these to set there texts accordingly i tried square bracket notation like this

```
 For i = 0 To 9 Step +1
            For Each btn In TableLayoutPanel7.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
                btn[i].text = i
            Next
        Next
```

this doesnt work is there any way to use i in the control name to reference it so it will just name them 1 - 9 respectively? any help anyone could provide on where to start would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How did you think that was going to work? What about VB syntax suggested that that could do anything useful? It looks like indexing a list in C# but 'btn' isn't a list and you're not using C#. You don't need two loops for a start. Just use the `For` loop, construct the name of the `Button` using string concatenation and then index the `Controls` collection of the `TableLayoutPanel` by that name.

Comment: ok can you break that down thats confusing all at once

Comment: In fact @jmcilhinney how would you even concatenate that could you give a pseudo code example?

Comment: "how would you even concatenate that". The same way you concatenate anything else. VB has a dedicated concatenation operator. Why would you need pseudo-code for something that you've probably seen a hundred times and any beginner tutorial will cover?

Comment: @jmcilhinney not what i mean would you just do for i = 0 to 9 step 1
btn + i.text = i

Comment: Firstly, 0 to 9 is 10 numbers so obviously not. If you need to get the numbers 1 to 9 in order to construct your names then it should be obvious that you need a loop from 1 to 9. Questions like this is what comes from not working out what your code actually has to do before trying to write it.  If you know what the code has to do, i.e. the steps rather than just the result, then you know to write code to do those specific steps, not some nebulous concept of what will get you to an end result.

Comment: Are the buttons always the same name? Are they added at runtime or design time? By using 2 `For` loops, you're effectively parsing through the list of buttons multiple times. What happens if btn1 has the text '2'? Is the order of the buttons vs the order of the button text values important? Lastly please keep it civil here. @jmcilhinney is one of our national treasures..

Comment: @AndrewMortimer theyre named btnseq1 to btnseq9 and no hes answered several of my questions and just expects me to know everything he says but the whole reason im here is to learn

Comment: I've added an answer with some samples. It may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the text:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    For Each btn In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        btn.Text = counter
        counter += 1
    Next
```

However, if you need to set specific values, then you need to test the name of each button:

```
    For Each btn In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        Select Case btn.Name
            Case "Button1"
                btn.Text = 1
            Case "Button2"
                btn.Text = 2
                'etc
        End Select
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you an answer i was waiting for still cant belive i genuinely didnt think of that myself but im not perfect than you my friend

Comment: In that second case, it would be more concise to simply have one line per `Button` and do away with the `Select Case` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Or, as I suggested:

```
For i = 1 To 9
    TableLayoutPanel7.Controls("btn" & i).Text = i.ToString()
Next
```